# How do you get access to insecure credentials in HTML logins without using APIs?

Tags: php, html

I'm doing an undergrad security course to simulate malware attacks. I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement a Broken Authentication vulnerability. I've chosen to simulate how to access credentials from a simple HTML/PHP login page, but almost every example I've fond uses APIs. Can someone help me code this? I want to keep it simple, since its for class.

```
<form action = "validate.php" method= "POST">
<table border = "0" padding = "5" cols = "2" >
<tr>
<td colspan = "2"><input name="usr" type = "text" placeholder = "Email" title = "Please enter your username here (e.g. johndoe1998@whomail.com)" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['usr']; ?>" class="auto-width" required/><?php echo $_SESSION['usrerr']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan = "2"><input name="pw" type = "password" placeholder = "********" title = "Please enter your password " value = "" class = "auto-width" required/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label style='font-size: 50%;'>Remember Me</label></td>
<td><input name="remember" type="checkbox" title="Remember Me for ONE Minute" value="yes" class="auto-width"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type = "submit" value = "Send Info" name = "lgn_submit"/></td>
<td><input type = "reset" value = "Clear"/></td>
<td><?php echo $_SESSION['err'] ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use SQL injection attack to demonstrate the Authentication vulnerability.